# What is the maximum entropy of a softmax output layer of a neural network?

Tags: entropy, upper-lower-bounds

Neural networks oftentimes apply the softmax operation to their output neurons which is defined by

$$s(x)_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{x_j}}$$

Here, $i$ is the index of an output neuron, and $N$ represents the total number of output neurons. That means that the sum of all output activations sum up to 1 and that the value of each output neuron lies between 0 and 1:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N s(x)_i = 1$$
$$0 \leq s(x)_i \leq 1$$

I would like to know if it is possible to calculate an upper bound of the output layer's entropy? Or do I first have to discretize the network's output in order to derive an upper bound for the entropy?

Comment: Are you trying to maximise $\sum -s(x_i) \log(s(x_i))$ ? Logarithms are concave functions

Comment: @Henry Yes, I would like to know if there is an upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^N -s(x_i) \log(s(x_i))$.

Comment: Try $\log(N)$ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Maximum

Comment: Do you have any assumption on the distribution of x_i?

Comment: @Mini No, I don't.

Comment: Then definitely you cannot establish anything better than $\log_2(N)$.